# Change javascript popup so that text doesn't go beyond the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the popup box so that it recognize the size of the window and adjust the box accordingly, or display it below the text?

In my code, almost all of the text goes beyond the text and is therefore invisible.

I tried to change the position from 'relative', but got nowhere near close to the desired effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Фёдор Ильи́ч Дан (настоящая фамилия Гу́рвич;1871—1947) — российский революционер и политический деятель, один из лидеров и теоретиков меньшевизма. Муж сестры Ю. О. Мартова Лидии Дан.<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Fedor_Dan.jpg" class="bubble"></span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to position your image to fit your popup.

```
.bubble{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maheshnathwani/82vq3shk/).

Comment: How could I change the popups to appear below the text, not above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your questions, it's very hard to understand what you want.

If you want the popup to be under the button, you should remove the bottom-value of ".popup .popuptext" and use "top" instead (eg "top: 20px")